# wrong name NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, package, classpath

I have a directory `/mydir`, package `p` `/mydir/p`, and class `cl` `/mydir/p/cl.class`

I do NOT want to `cd` into the package directory.
How could I execute my class from outside the package directory, say directory `/my/otherdir/here`, if possible?

```
/my/otherdir/here>java -cp /mydir/p p.cl
```

receives a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: p/cl` error.

Obviously `java -cp /mydir/p cl` throws a `wrong name:p/cl` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package directory `p` does not need to be on the class path. It's its parent directory `/mydir` that does. The package needs to be included while providing the class name (as `p.cl`) though.

```
java -cp /mydir p.cl
```